# How to pause work on weekend, specifically between Friday 5pm and Monday 7am

Tags: c#

I am trying to pause work from being done when it is weekend. Specifically stop doing work at 5pm Friday and resume at 6am Monday.

Here is what I have so far, but it is not working as expected:

```
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        var testDay = date.AddHours(54);
        if ((testDay.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && testDay.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday) || (testDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday && testDay.Hour < 17) || (testDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && testDay.Hour > 6))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do work");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pause work");
        }
```

**Today is Wednesday so I created testDay to be 54 hours later which would set datetime to my conditions that will pause work.

Comment: When debugging complex Boolean expressions, it is often helpful to break the expression into smaller pieces, giving each piece a meaningful name by assigning that piece to a named variable, and combining those variables into the final result. Your Boolean expression simply does not reflect what it is you say you want to achieve. If you don't know how to use a debugger, well...now would be an _excellent_ time for you to acquire that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally find it easier to turn this one around, because there are fewer conditions that way than testing every other day of the week*:

"If after5onfriday or saturday or sunday or  before6onmonday" then "pause" else "do"

Also incorporated Peter's suggestion, as it's a great way of reducing long lines and making code more self documenting

```
public static void Main()
{
    var date = DateTime.Now;
    while(date < DateTime.Now.AddDays(8)){
        Print(date);
        date = date.AddHours(3);
    }
}

static void Print(DateTime testDay){
    var dow = testDay.DayOfWeek;
    var isSat = dow == DayOfWeek.Saturday;
    var isSun = dow == DayOfWeek.Sunday;
    var isFriLate = dow == DayOfWeek.Friday && testDay.Hour >= 17;
    var isMonEarly = dow == DayOfWeek.Monday && testDay.Hour < 6;
    
    if (isFriLate || isSat || isSun || isMonEarly)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(testDay + " - Pause work");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(testDay + " - Do work");
    }
}
```

```
6/30/2021 6:07:39 PM - Do work
6/30/2021 9:07:39 PM - Do work
7/1/2021 12:07:39 AM - Do work
7/1/2021 3:07:39 AM - Do work
7/1/2021 6:07:39 AM - Do work
7/1/2021 9:07:39 AM - Do work
7/1/2021 12:07:39 PM - Do work
7/1/2021 3:07:39 PM - Do work
7/1/2021 6:07:39 PM - Do work
7/1/2021 9:07:39 PM - Do work
7/2/2021 12:07:39 AM - Do work
7/2/2021 3:07:39 AM - Do work
7/2/2021 6:07:39 AM - Do work
7/2/2021 9:07:39 AM - Do work
7/2/2021 12:07:39 PM - Do work
7/2/2021 3:07:39 PM - Do work
7/2/2021 6:07:39 PM - Pause work
7/2/2021 9:07:39 PM - Pause work
7/3/2021 12:07:39 AM - Pause work
7/3/2021 3:07:39 AM - Pause work
7/3/2021 6:07:39 AM - Pause work
7/3/2021 9:07:39 AM - Pause work
7/3/2021 12:07:39 PM - Pause work
7/3/2021 3:07:39 PM - Pause work
7/3/2021 6:07:39 PM - Pause work
7/3/2021 9:07:39 PM - Pause work
7/4/2021 12:07:39 AM - Pause work
7/4/2021 3:07:39 AM - Pause work
7/4/2021 6:07:39 AM - Pause work
7/4/2021 9:07:39 AM - Pause work
7/4/2021 12:07:39 PM - Pause work
7/4/2021 3:07:39 PM - Pause work
7/4/2021 6:07:39 PM - Pause work
7/4/2021 9:07:39 PM - Pause work
7/5/2021 12:07:39 AM - Pause work
7/5/2021 3:07:39 AM - Pause work
7/5/2021 6:07:39 AM - Do work
7/5/2021 9:07:39 AM - Do work
7/5/2021 12:07:39 PM - Do work
7/5/2021 3:07:39 PM - Do work
7/5/2021 6:07:39 PM - Do work
7/5/2021 9:07:39 PM - Do work
7/6/2021 12:07:39 AM - Do work
7/6/2021 3:07:39 AM - Do work
7/6/2021 6:07:39 AM - Do work
7/6/2021 9:07:39 AM - Do work
7/6/2021 12:07:39 PM - Do work
7/6/2021 3:07:39 PM - Do work
7/6/2021 6:07:39 PM - Do work
7/6/2021 9:07:39 PM - Do work
7/7/2021 12:07:39 AM - Do work
7/7/2021 3:07:39 AM - Do work
7/7/2021 6:07:39 AM - Do work
7/7/2021 9:07:39 AM - Do work
7/7/2021 12:07:39 PM - Do work
7/7/2021 3:07:39 PM - Do work
7/7/2021 6:07:39 PM - Do work
7/7/2021 9:07:39 PM - Do work
7/8/2021 12:07:39 AM - Do work
7/8/2021 3:07:39 AM - Do work
7/8/2021 6:07:39 AM - Do work
7/8/2021 9:07:39 AM - Do work
7/8/2021 12:07:39 PM - Do work
7/8/2021 3:07:39 PM - Do work
7/8/2021 6:07:39 PM - Do work
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/lgwpCm

*<sub>(though you could use the day of week enum as a number, and test for a range >= tue and <= thu)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement will evaluate true at all times on Friday and will result in doing work all day Friday, which isn't what you want. Flipping boolean expressions is a really common mistake when using a negative expression.

In this situation, you could write out your boolean expressions for what you *want* to happen. You can do this for all the cases that you want work to happen, all the cases you want work not to happen, or both. Once you determine what you actually want to happen you can use these expressions. Since its 7 days you can do this manually. (Only including logic for the Do Not Work condition because that's what you used)

Do not work if it is:

- A. Friday After 5PM `testDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday && testDay.Hour > 17`
- B. Saturday `testDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday`
- C. Sunday `testDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday`
- D. Monday Before 6AM `testDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && testDay.Hour < 6`

*Notice how I changed some of the greater than and less than signs

These would be OR'ed together to get all do not work cases. *(A || B || C || D)*. To get all of the Do Work cases you flip the *entire* expression. ***!**(A || B || C || D)*

If you want to use the Do Not Work cases to describe the do work cases, you have to flip the expression. You did this partially, but not correctly. I encourage you to look into DeMorgans law after writing the complete expression. You don't have to expand it out like DeMorgans law since C# will do that for you, but understanding DeMorgans law and how to use it helps you be more aware of these types of mistakes.